# Redirect on "Leave this Page" button click

Tags: javascript

I write following function

```
window.onbeforeunload = function(){
  return 'Are you sure you want to leave?';
};
```

Now I'm want when user click "Leave this Page" button then it's redirect another page. Is that possible ?

Comment: No, it is not possible.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No it's not. Imagine what a mess the web would be when one could "take control" over users' browsers in such a harmful way. Besides the fact that it's horrible UX it would be grist to the mill for phishing sites.